# android cordova iframe could not display the web content

Tags: android, cordova, iframe

I have config the config.xml in android cordova to let all the domain can be loaded.like this:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

And the web page that i need to load has CSP configuration like this:frame-ancestors 'self' *.sc.com *.standardchartered.com *.standardchartered.co.in *.standardchartered.co.th *.standardchartered.com.hk *.standardchartered.com.my *.standardchartered.com.sg *.standardchartered.co.id *.standardchartered.com.tw

By using Charles to catch response that i find the http status is 200. Even more amazing thing is this problem only be occurred in android, ios and web do not appear.

Seeking for your help, please...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

You are loading url into an iframe in the main web view, which requires you to allow access to that content in the config.xml file.

```
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />
```

Refer this url: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Comment: I try to add some whitelist in comfig.xml but it is still not working.it is still displaying a white page.

Comment: The web page i need load is https, and in whitelist i have add both http and https.By the way, do you know why cordova_plugins.js could not be found,this js file is missing.